# CORS not working with hapijs and socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, cors, hapi.js

so i have a server set up using hapi js and socket.io

```
var hapi = require('hapi');
var server = new hapi.Server();
server.connection({
    host : 'localhost',
    port: 3000,
    routes: {cors: true}
});
var io = require("socket.io")(server.listener);
```

on the client

```
var io = socket.connect(':3000');
```

when i access from localhost everything works fine, but when i access from the external IP i get the CORS error and can't make it work, on the server i've tried `io.set( "origins", "*:*" );` didn't work, and `io.set('transports', ['websocket', 'xhr-polling', 'jsonp-polling', 'htmlfile', 'flashsocket']);` also didn't work and throws a bad request error on the browser.
am i missing something?
thanks you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the problem was setting the host to localhost, instead i used 0.0.0.0 as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043926/node-js-connect-only-works-on-localhost)

Answer (score 6):

Can you try setting the origin explicitly instead of using "*"? You probably don't want to use "*" in production anyway.

Try using:

```
server.connection({
  host : 'localhost',
  port: 3000,
  routes: {
    cors: {
      origin: ['your_origin_here']
    }
  }
});
```

Also sometimes there is an OPTIONS preflighted request made to check the origin, maybe share that as well to make sure CORS is being set properly?