# Getting 404 on sails project when reaching through machine name

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I am pretty new to sails module on node.js

I created a basic web-app and it launches good on 
http://localhost:8081/test

but when I try to access with my machine name like
http://mymachinename:8081/test

it goes 404 page. I also tried to access from another PC in same domain and same 404 error.

I expect both requests should return 200 response.

Am I missing something?

Comment: So this your local development machine?

Comment: Yes, I am testing on my local.

Comment: For access from another PC, use the local IP address.  Did you add mymachinename to your /etc/hosts (assuming mac or linux)?

Comment: I tried with IP as well and it did not worked. I am getting response from sails but as 404.

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043926/node-js-connect-only-works-on-localhost ?

Comment: @xkcd149 that question lead me to resolution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a little information and some suggestions. Here I am on MAC OS X.

First, yes it should work out of the box:

```
$ sails new app && cd $_ && npm install
$ sails lift --port 1338

http://127.0.0.1:1338/
http://192.168.0.5:1338/
http://mymachine.local:1338/
```

are all equivalent (loopback, my local IP, my local machine name respectively).

Try a port scan and see if the port you think it is running on is actually running or else already occupied.

On Mac OS X.

```
lsof -i :1337
```

Perhaps try starting on a different port:

```
sails lift --port 1338   (i did this for the above)
```

Did you install sails globally? If so, you could try uninstalling and reinstalling:

```
npm uninstall -g sails
npm install -g sails
```

If you are still having problems, they are local and very unlikely specific to SailsJS. Do usual troubleshooting for network / port related issues locally etc.

Finally, to gain access for other users to your local machine, i usually use [ngrok](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngrok). Ngrok exposes your localhost to the web - example:

```
$ npm install ngrok -g
$ ngrok http 1338
```

See this example usage:

[image]

In the above example, the locally running instance of sails at: **localhost:1338** is now available on the Internet served at: **http://840fa6c4.ngrok.io**

Comment: Reference given by @xkcd149 lead me the answer but I will accept this answer since it goes similar walk-through for solution of the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @Teomanshipahi - hey, thanks - appreciate it. And hope you enjoy SailsJS - i think it is pretty awesome and used it in production (commercially)  in 2014 - improved since then. the IRC channel #sailsjs on chat.freenode.net is a good place to paste SOF questions too, there is usually someone knowledgeable on there ready to offer help / advice.

Comment: @Teomanshipahi - i have provided a little more context on ngrok usage - it was a refresher for myself also... been a while.