# Strongloop only binds to 127.0.0.1

Tags: node.js, vagrant, strongloop

This question is on similar lines as this - [Node.js connect only works on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043926/node-js-connect-only-works-on-localhost) - with the exception AFAIK that the only configuration available in Strongloop is the config.json.

I have tried using "0.0.0.0" in the config.json host value as shown below, but the netstat still shows it is bound only to 127.0.0.1

```
{
  "host": "0.0.0.0",
  "restApiRoot": "/api",
  "host": "0.0.0.0",
  "port": 3000,
  "remoting": {
    "context": {
      "enableHttpContext": false
    },
...
...
```

This is the log of netstat:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:51733           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

This is my network config:

```
vagrant@precise64:~/projects/loopback-example-offline-sync/server$ ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:88:0c:a6
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe88:ca6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7428 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7205 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:4740627 (4.7 MB)  TX bytes:3865969 (3.8 MB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:bf:af:6b
          inet addr:33.33.33.10  Bcast:33.33.33.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:febf:af6b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1325 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1565 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:101155 (101.1 KB)  TX bytes:238095 (238.0 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:909 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:909 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:3429927 (3.4 MB)  TX bytes:3429927 (3.4 MB)
```

I am able to SSH into the vagrant box using 33.33.33.10. Replacing 0.0.0.0 with 33.33.33.10 also did not work. I tried removing the host attribute completely from the config, that didn't work either. UFW is disabled.

I have no other option to try, hence posting on SO :-)

Comment: Kill the process and start it again.

Comment: I did restart the process after each configuration change, but no joy. In fact, even rebooted the machine several times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I figured it out. The config is actually driven from Gruntfile.js. It's too confusing. There are too many places the host is defined.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem, can you please share the solution? thanks

Comment: You have to change it in your Gruntfile.js

Comment: well that was very helpful