# Accessing NodeJS server from remote machine on local network shows a blank page

Tags: node.js, http, reactjs, firewall, ngrok

I wanted to test my ReactJS + NodeJS website on another machine on my LAN, so I changed the server host ip from `localhost` to `0.0.0.0` as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043926/node-js-connect-only-works-on-localhost) answer. I noticed that although I could access the server from a remote machine, all I could see was the title and favicon (the rest was a blank page). I tried another approach of using the [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) module as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34659560/2057069) (which happens to be the answer to the same question as the previous link). I still got the same blank page.

The `GET` requests to the server are shown below (as shown by ngrok).

[image: GET requests to the server shown by ngrok]

`/landing` is a page I was trying to access. Can someone explain whats happening?

**PS**: The server is running on a Mac and I'm trying to access the page on an Ubuntu machine. Also, I'm using [this](https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit) react-redux boilerplate. Webpack is also being used along with hot reloading.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try changing port settings in firewall?

Go to firewall settings and allow the respective port for inbound