# I'm having trouble opening a port into Azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have a simple Azure Windows Server VM set up and I have a NodeJS app running in it. Within the VM (using Windows RDP), I can access the app in a browser at http://localhost:4200. However, I can't manage to open port 4200 so that I can access it from the outside using my VM's IP.

I've tried the obvious, as outlined here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal

The crazy thing is that I also have another app, running as a Windows service on port 8080, and that one works. I have a rule for each, and I can't see what I'm doing differently:

[image: Inbound traffic rules]

I also completely disabled the Windows Firewall within the VM, and it still doesn't work. Can't get through at all.

Comment: Is your app running via IIS? if not, perhaps IIS is grabbing the port?

Comment: iis grabbing port 4200? but why?

Comment: Any chance your internet provider blocks connection to that port? I'd propose to try another one like 8082 and see the result.

Comment: @4c74356b41 just tossing out the idea, to check.

Comment: can you confirm your app listens on the ip address you are trying to access it? it might be bound to localhost only, thats rare, but it can happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, it seems that your app is only listening on `127.0.0.1`. Please check as the following ways.

1.Check the port listening.

```
netstat -ant|findstr 4200
```

Please ensure your service is listening on `0.0.0.0` not `127.0.0.1`. If you service is listening on `127.0.0.0`, please modify it. You could refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043926/node-js-connect-only-works-on-localhost).

2.Please ensure your VM is listening on `tcp`  not `tcp6`.