# Problem accessing dockerized node application from outside of container

Tags: angular, windows, docker

i have been trying to dockerize an angular project, using Docker Desktop for windows, with linux containers, and Hyper-V.

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /var/app

EXPOSE 4200

COPY package*.json ./
COPY proxy*.json ./

COPY . .
RUN npm install @angular/cli -g
#Custom dependencies
RUN npm config set registry http://maven.corp.com.br:8081/artifactory/api/npm/
RUN npm install

RUN npm run build:dev

ENTRYPOINT npm start
```

i build it and can run it just fine with:

```
docker build -t name .

docker run -p 4200:4200 name
```

The problem is, when i try to access https://localhost:4200 from my windows pc, i get ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED.

However, if i go into the container cli, and use Links (the command line web browser https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOg5O.gif) to access the url, it works just fine, i'm just having issues trying to access it from my windows pc.

I tried using the host.docker.domain dns aswell but no success.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043926/node-js-connect-only-works-on-localhost

that is your issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `ENTRYPOINT npm start` to

`ENTRYPOINT npm start -- --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check`

or update `package.json`

`"start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check",`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much @paltaa , all i had to do was change from "npm start" to a custom "ng serve" with the flag --host 0.0.0.0"