# Change ip Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mean-stack

I created a mean stack application, I am deploying it in a virtual machine
the problem is that I need to change the localhost(localhost:4200) address to the ip of the machine 10.10.10.15(10.10.10.15:4200) I don't know how to do it

```
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express")
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const db = require("./db/db")
const header_middleware = require("./middlewares/header")

const postRouter = require("./Routes/post");
const userRoutes = require("./Routes/user");
const profileRoutes = require("./Routes/profile");

var cors = require('cors');


const app = express()
app.use(cors({origin: '*'}));
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000


app.use(express.json())
app.use(header_middleware)
const directory = path.join(__dirname, './images');
app.use("/images", express.static(directory));
// app.use("/", express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'angular')));

app.use("/api/posts", postRouter)
app.use("/api/user", userRoutes);
app.use("/api/profile", profileRoutes);


app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World!')
  })

app.listen(PORT, (req,res) => {
    
    console.log(`app is listening to PORT ${PORT}`)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using your ip you can use your computer-name:4300 in your browser for example `laptop-xxxxx:4300`. To find your computer name you can go to about in your settings and it will say the name of your computer. If that doesn’t work check this answer out:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/34659560/11365636

Comment: app.listen(PORT,"10.10.10.15", (req,res) => {
    
    console.log(`app is listening to PORT ${PORT}`)
}) not work