# Connection refused with a basic HTTP server on AWS EC2

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I know there are lots of resources on this topic, but I think I've done everything correctly and I still can't connect to my server.

I've started a simple node.js server on port 80.

```
sudo netstat -tnlp | grep 80
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3657/node
```

```
curl localhost:80
Welcome Node.js
```

I've configured the Security group for this instance as well as the VPC to allow traffic.
[image: security rules]

I've made sure there is no local firewall and that the VPC ACL is not blocking traffic (not that I expected it, since this is a completely new instance.)

```
service iptables status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status iptables.service
Unit iptables.service could not be found.
```

The output when I try to connect from my local machine:

```
 curl 3.xxx.xxx.xxx
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:03 --:--:--     0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 3.xxx.xxx.xxx port 80: Connection refused
```

Are there any other ideas on what to check next?

Comment: It's interesting that that says "connection refused" when trying to connect from your local machine - would suggest to me that the request is reaching your EC2 instance and then being refused there perhaps. At a guess, maybe your node isn't configured to connect to external clients... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043926/node-js-connect-only-works-on-localhost

Comment: on which port you have started your node js server, is it 80 or something else like 3000?check your app.js and check on which port your server is listening

Comment: Your app is likely running on 3000.

Comment: The netstat command and `curl localhost` command are intended to show that it is running on port 80 on the EC2 instance.

Comment: @Jack Thank you! That was the problem. You can write an answer which I will accept, or if you don't I will write an answer with some more details.

Comment: I might leave it to you to answer - it'll probably be more useful for other viewers to have more details :-) Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

The answer to my problem was https://stackoverflow.com/a/14045163/2369000. The boilerplate code that I copied used a method to only listen to requests that originated from localhost. This could have been detected from the netstat output, which said `127.0.0.1:80` for the listening address. The answer was to use `.listen(80, "0.0.0.0")` or just `.listen(80)` since the default behavior is to listen for requests from any IP address.